# Change style of certain selectItem in <h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, seam

In my xhtml page I am using a `<h:selectOneMenu>` component. In order to populate data, I am using a `<s:selectItems>` component inside the  component. What I need is to conditionally change the style of a certain `selectItem`. Is it possible or is there an alternative way? 
For an example I need to change the color of an option if the label of it is '***pencil***'.
I am using **jboss-seam** and the namespace '**s**' refers to the seam tag library.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}" id="myCombo">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="-Please select-" itemValue=""/>
   <s:selectItems value="#{bean.items}" var="item" label="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Check the generated HTML output, copy it and try editing it accordingly in the plain HTML code so that you get the desired result. Then ask how to port exactly the desired HTML output back to JSF. I'd bet that you already stucks getting it right in the plain HTML side (at least, when you want something more complex than just changing the option color and certainly when you want get it to work across all browsers). Then you should maybe realize that it simply isn't possible to achieve the same in JSF --which is basically a HTML code generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative way with `javascript`. My `js` code was like this. However this is just a simplified code which shows the concept.

```
<script>      
  window.onload = function() {
    var options = document.getElementById("myForm:myCombo").options;
    for(var i = 0; i &lt; options.length; i++) {
      if(options[i].innerHTML == 'pencil') {
        options[i].style.color = 'red';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```